# Javascript как выполнить функцию через заданное программой время?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, settimeout

День добрый!
Мне нужно, чтобы моя функция в Javascript выполнялась каждый раз быстрее, то есть нужно установить тайм аут функциями `setTimeout` или `setInterval` так, чтобы можно было его регулировать из самой функции. То есть например мне нужно, чтобы 1 раз функция выполнилась через 5 секунд, потом через 4 секунды после завершения выполнения предыдущей функции, и.т.д. Время между функциями должно становиться меньше каждый раз. Буду очень благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсивный setTimeout

Важная альтернатива setInterval – рекурсивный setTimeout:

```
var timer = 5;
var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
    console.log( "тик "+ timer);
    timer-- ;
    if(timer != 0){
        timerId = setTimeout(tick, timer*1000);
    }
    else
        console.log('stop');
}, timer*1000);
```

В коде выше следующее выполнение планируется сразу после окончания предыдущего.

Рекурсивный setTimeout – более гибкий метод тайминга, чем setInterval, так как время до следующего выполнения можно запланировать по-разному, в зависимости от результатов текущего.

Вместо console.log('stop') можете подставить свои функции

Answer (score 1):

Считайте время следующего запуска, прибавляя уменьшающийся интервал. Часто вызывайте функцию, которая проверит текущее системное время и сравнит его с временем очередного запуска. Это позволяет точнее отмерять время, чем `setTimeout()` или `setInterval()`. Величина ошибки ограничена коротким интервалом вызова.

```js
var nextTime, interval=3000, minInterval = 300;

function checkTime() {
  var now = (new Date).getTime();
  if( nextTime && now < nextTime) return;
  if( !nextTime) nextTime = now;
  nextTime += interval;
  interval *= 0.7; // уменьшение в геометрической прогрессии
  interval = Math.max( minInterval, interval);
  
  // здесь какая-то полезная нагрузка функции
  document.body.appendChild( document.createElement('span'));
}

window.setInterval( checkTime, 100);
```

```css
body{line-height: 12px}span {display:inline-block;width:12px; height: 12px;background-color: #333;margin-right: 2px;}
```